# Top alignment in multicols environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

I would like to add a signature section at the bottom of a contract. On the left column the third-party signatures and on the right the company signatures.

Unfortunately, `multicols` does a flush on the left column. The signature box is put at the bottom of the environment. How can I prevent this to happen?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\signature}{
    \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=4pt,linewidth=0pt,backgroundcolor=gray!20]
        \vskip 1.5cm
        \tiny \textsf{Signature}
    \end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}   
Here is the contract\dots    
\vfill

\begin{multicols}{2}
John G Baldwin \\ 4323 Traders Alley \\ 61105 Kansas City \\
\signature
\columnbreak

Nathaniel S Bennett \\ 2166 Lighthouse Drive \\ 65616 Branson \\
\signature

Romeo B Walker \\ 4402 Snider Street \\ 81003 Pueblo Colorado \\
+1 719 937 78 78 \\
\signature

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so by using `\vfill\null`, `\null` places another box, which prevents `multicols` from ignoring the `\vfill` before `\columnbreak`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\signature}{
    \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=4pt,linewidth=0pt,backgroundcolor=gray!20]
        \vskip 1.5cm
        \tiny \textsf{Signature}
    \end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}   
Here is the contract\dots    
\vfill

\begin{multicols}{2}
John G Baldwin \\ 4323 Traders Alley \\ 61105 Kansas City \\
\signature
\vfill
\null
\columnbreak

Nathaniel S Bennett \\ 2166 Lighthouse Drive \\ 65616 Branson \\
\signature

Romeo B Walker \\ 4402 Snider Street \\ 81003 Pueblo Colorado \\
+1 719 937 78 78 \\
\signature

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I was missing the magic `\null`